# Filter and sort columm

Tags: sorting, awk, filter, sed

I learnt awk and sed, but I'm stuck at this problem, can anyone help me?
I have a table like this:

```
a1 a2 a3 a4 
b1 b2 b3 b4
c1 c2 c3 c4
```

So I want to filter value at odd and even columns like this:
*table 1*:

```
a1
a3
b1
b3
c1
c3
```

and ***table 2***:

```
a2 
a4
b2
b4
c2
c4
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Which one is it (awk, sed, or c)?  Also format your tables with markdown otherwise it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @AllanWind do it by anyway you can

Comment: Please explain how your question is related to `sorting`, which is one of tags you have used

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to work in `awk` using:

```
awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i += 2) print $i > "table.1"
       for (i = 2; i <= NF; i += 2) print $i > "table.2" }' data
```

For each line, the first loop writes the odd fields to `table.1` and the second loop writes the even fields to `table.2`.  It will even work with different numbers of columns in each line if the input data is not wholly consistent.  A single pass through the input data generates both output files.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the maximum number of fields (say, 100+) just use cut:

```
$ echo 'a1 a2 a3 a4
b1 b2 b3 b4
c1 c2 c3 c4' | cut -d' ' -f $(seq -s, 2 2 100) | tr ' ' '\n'
a2
a4
b2
b4
c2
c4
```

and for the odd ones seq would just start at 1.

Here's the same thing in awk (i=1 for the odd ones):

```
echo ... | awk '{for(i=2; i<=NF;i+=2){ print $i}}'
```

Comment: I run with this guide but I just work with odd columm, but with even columm, it shows space line after a4,b4 and c4

Comment: @ThanhMinh space line?  newline?  Your example output has new lines after each field which is why I added it.

Comment: I put all data in file (not echo), so I use this command: cat file.txt | awk...

Comment: @ThanhMinh yes?

Comment: @ThanhMinh sounds like you have DOS line endings, see [why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it) for one manifestation of that and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/ \+/\n/g;s/^\n\|\n$//' file | sed -ne '1~2w table1' -e '2~2w table2'
```

Replace space(s) by newlines and remove leading or trailing newlines.

Pipe output into a second invocation of sed which directs odd lines to table1 and even lines to table2.

Or you may prefer to use:

```
paste -sd' '  file | tr -s ' ' '\n' | sed -ne '1~2w table1' -e '2~2w table2'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i > ("table" (i+1)%2+1)}' file
```

```
$ head table*
==> table1 <==
a1
a3
b1
b3
c1
c3

==> table2 <==
a2
a4
b2
b4
c2
c4
```